# #import iAd in .m instead of .h

Tags: cocoa-touch, delegates, iad

Is there any way to `#import`  in the .m file instead of the .h file? The problem is that I need to specify that the view controller is a `ADBannerViewDelegate` in the .h file, which it doesn't recognize if `iAd` is imported in the .m file.
Is there some way around this, or am I stuck having to `#import` `iAd` every time I `#import` that view controller?

Comment: Always include the header (.h) instead of implementation file (.m). Import it in every view controller you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can put all iAd code in the `.m` file; you will just need to use a class extension (very common).  Class extensions, allow you to declare variables, include delegates, create properties, etc. all from the `.m` file.

Class extensions sit near the top of your `.m` file, before the `@implementation` statement.

For example:

```
//.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController
@end


//.m
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

//The following is the class extension
@interface HomeViewController () <ADBannerViewDelegate> //add any delegates here {
    IBOutlet ADBannerView *ad;  //A reference to the ad
    BOOL someBOOL;              //You can put any variables here
}
- (void)someMethod:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *someView;
@end
```

Note: The class extension must end with an `@end`, and then the regular class body follows: `@implementation HomeViewController...`

Apple's docs do a good job further explaining class extensions.  Check them out [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

---

Also worth noting, theres a special file automatically created with your project called a "Pre-compiled Header".  This file is a place you can import other classes you intend to use throughout your project so you won't have to manually import them in every class.

Heres an example of a PCH:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <iAd/iAd.h>
    //Put any other classes here and you can use them from any file
#endif
```

If you look in your project files, under Supporting Files, you should see `You-Project-Name-Prefix.pch`

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks!
Is there ever any reason to put protocols in the .h file then?

Comment: Glad it helped.  And I don't want to say there is **never** any reason to put protocols in the .h file, but since the creation of class extensions I can't think of an instance where I have.  Really with class extensions, I've found minimal need for .h files - except for public variables.